# How can I acess a collection from another collection? [ Flutter ] [ Firebase ]

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections users und groups. In the users collection, I have already stored the id of each group inside the groups collection. Now I have to search for the groupID inside the users collection and use them to find the matching groupID inside the groups collection.

How can I do that?

What is this process called?
(acess a collection from another collection)

Comment: you can fetch the group id from users collection or make another request to the group collection this time retrieving the group document with he group ID. Alternatively, you may like to put the group Ids as references inside the an array as a field of user. This way you will not need to create a new subcollection inside users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its hard to understand your question but i assume you are asking about Queries.

create a new database reference that points to the Users Collection and add a Query like below.

```
..collection('users').where('groupID', isEqualTo: your_groupID_variable).getDocuments();
```

if you want to run this for each group, use a forEach.